# MySQL data import from excel sheet

Tags: mysql, excel

I have an excel sheet.That contains the details like 
[image]

I have an existing table called 'employee' with following structure and data
[image]

Now I don't have the column Gender in the table.I want to create a new column 'Gender' and update the values according to the excel sheet.I am using MySQL workbench.Is there any option to do the updation.Thanks in advance for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column 'Gender' on your database, Assuming that there are existing data from your database.. you could try something like this:

Use `UPDATE tablename SET GENDERcolumn = GENDERExcelValue WHERE EMPLOYEECODEColumn = EMPLOYEECODEExcel AND NAMEColumn = NAMEExcel.`